# Уместно ли привлекать внимание к ответам на собственные вопросы в чате?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, нытьё

Насколько приветствуется "шаринг" знаний в форме вопрос+ответ?

**Дано:**

Создал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484614/17609) и сам же на него [ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484615/17609). Оформлял старательно. И получил почти 0 реакции. Это расстраивает и поэтому тут будет метка [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91).

При этом в справке писано, что подобное поощряется.

**Вопрос:**

Насколько уместно привлекать внимание к таким вопросоответам, кидая ссылки на них в чат, например? Не повлечёт ли это толпу минусов от пользователей, не считающих репутацию важной?

Comment: Проверьте и узнаете )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сначала мне индульгенция нужна)

Answer (score 15):

На такие вопросы очень уместно кидаться рефссылками во внешние источники — друзьям, в твиттер, в блог.

- Получаете специальные знаки, когда много пользователей перейдут по ссылке.
- Привлекаете новых участников на Ru.SO.
- Не провоцируете людей в чате =)

Специально «нагонять трафик» из чата — не очень хорошо, на мой взгляд. В конце концов, разве ваш труд не равен труду двоих людей, один из которых задал вопрос, а другой — ответил (предположим, что они были столь же старательны)? Тогда эти двое имеют такое же право прийти в общий чат и пиарить свои сообщения. Итого у нас будет почти три сотни ссылок в день.

> Насколько приветствуется "шаринг" знаний в форме вопрос+ответ?

Приветствуется, но ведь вопрос-то не об этом. Голоса, как верно пишет PashaPash, показывают степень полезности вопроса широкому кругу читателей. Ваши +1/+2 за 4 дня это ещё очень хорошо. Например, у меня есть [самоответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444935/181472), на который было потрачено часа два работы. *С прошлого августа* 1 голос за вопрос*, два за ответ. Это в общем-то нормально, некоторые темы интересны очень узкому кругу.

<sub>* Поправка. 2 голоса за и один против.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Плюсы и минусы должны оценивать полезность сообщения для сообщества, а не сам факт ответа на собственный вопрос.

Comment: К сожалению это не всегда работает... У нас множество вопросов/ответов с громадным кол-вом просмотров и 0-1 плюсами.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб значит никто не решил что эти ответы и вопросы настолько полезны, чтобы нажать на них +. А количеству просмотров для вопросов до апреля 2015-го вообще доверять не стоит.

Answer (score -6):

Желание поделиться знаниями должно поощряться всеми возможными способами и любое адекватное привлечение внимания к таким сообщениям должно также приветствоваться и ТС должен поощряться плюсами.

Answer (score -10):

Возможность поделиться знаниями уже достаточная награда и если ТС хочет ещё репутации за это - его надо заминусовать.