# Нужно ли дополнительно поощрять самоответы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, репутация, самоответы

Есть как минимум две ситуации, когда автор задает вопрос и сам пишет на него ответ (назовём это «самоответом»).

1. Автор — эксперт в некоторой теме. Он формулирует некоторую популярную, важную и/или интересную ему проблему и описывает её решение в качестве ответа.
2. Автор сталкивается с некоторой проблемой на практике и сам находит её решение. Бывает, он задает вопрос до нахождения решения, а после может опубликовать ответ. В других случаях автор сам находит решение и хочет опубликовать его на SO, чтобы поделиться знанием с коллегами. Тут он становится экспертом из первого пункта.

Тут есть несколько проблем.

Подробные экспертные ответы обычно неплохо оцениваются (хотя куда им до [трёх строчек о поиске работы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3893/181472)). А если новый участник опубликует решение своей задачи, то есть шанс, что это вообще никак не будет замечено и вознаграждено. Разумеется, +15 репутации за галочку он не получит — вопрос собственный.

Вопросы:

- Стоит ли дополнительно поощрять автора, чтобы он опубликовал найденное им решение для его вопроса?
- Стоит ли дополнительно поощрять подробные экспертные самоответы?
- Если да, то каким образом уместно это делать? (например, публиковать в специальном чате, сделать дайджест на Мете, устроить конкурс с наградами в виде репутации...)

Связанные вопросы:

- [Как заинтересовать автора вопроса публиковать найденное им решение в виде ответа?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/696/181472)
- [Уместно ли привлекать внимание к ответам на собственные вопросы в чате?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2388/181472)

Comment: Чую если давать репутацию в награду - то начнется еще большая чреда самоответов с целью поднакрутить, повысить самооценочку, а не с целью поделиться знаниями.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: если это будут плохие ответы — они наоборот принесут минусы.

Comment: Таки да, даёшь дайджесты! И конкурсы! Так мы и вопросов интересных от экспертов получим и прекратим [meta-tag:нытьё] из-за отстутствия качественных вопросов!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, формат «вопросо-ответ» подразумевает, что на качественный вопрос уже есть (качественный) ответ. т.е., как средство от *нытья* это не поможет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну, возможно же, что вопросоответ кого-то заинтересует и этот кто-то ещё более лучшее решение предложит)

Comment: вопросы подобные вопросу о поиске работы должны удаляться, т.к. это явный оффтопик, который скорее всего остался еще от хешкода. Он не имеет ничего общего с тематикой so и никакой исторической важности на наш взгляд в нем нет. Загадка как вообще, в рамках so, можно было сказать "спасибо" за такой вопрос...

Comment: @NickVolynkin Было бы странным если человек, который хочет себе залить репы опубликовывал бы самоответ не представляя вообще то, о чем в ответе написано) Конечно он будет подбирать получше. Еще дело в чем. Один человек опубликовал вопрос. Долго думал думал решал... решил проблему. пришел на форум, а ответов нет, ну и запостил свой ответ. А другое, как некоторые... берут вопрос с ответом (где много плюсов)  enSO, переводят и постят.. И всё. А порой еще проще. Из какого-либо русского ресурса копи паст и вопрос и ответ.

Comment: Кстати. иногда ощущение складывается, что некоторые как на вопрос так и на ответ сразу плюс ставят, не читая.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: я думаю, что оба варианта хороши и заслуживают той репутации, которую приносят — как самостоятельно найденное решение, так и хороший перевод. Но к переводу есть требования в соблюдении авторских прав. Если просто копипаста без указания автора — плохо, конечно.

Comment: @Alex: про поиск работы у нас был, пожалуй, самый большой холивар за историю ru.SO. Отзвуки той битвы остались в чате и тут: [Давайте решим, что нам делать с вопросом о поиске работы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1771)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: у вас тут соображений накопилось уже на целый ответ. Может, оформите в ответ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `Из какого-либо русского ресурса копи паст и вопрос и ответ`
А не это ли является частью идеологии StackOverflow, как хранилища знаний? Может и копипаст, но ведь плюс в копилку ресурсов и полезных советов.

Answer (score 12):

Добавить серебряный и золотой аналоги знака "Самоучка"

Comment: Отличная идея, в дополнение к Сократу.

Answer (score 9):

Нет, зачем?

- Экспертные самоответы уже неплохо поощряют. По моему личному опыту, можно сказать, что самоответы оцениваются лучше, чем обычные ответы. В моем случае, средний самоответ зарабатывает 142 баллов репутации, а средный обычный ответ - 32.
- Что касается самоответы новичков: это хорошо, конечно, когда новички сами разбираются, и при этом публиковают самоответы. В то же время, вопросы от новичков, как правило, интересно мало кому, кроме автора вопроса, и соответственные ответы обычно не очень интересны тоже. Естественно, не получают большую оценку.

Answer (score 6):

Поощрять стоит за полезную помощь, а не за действие. Самоответ есть действие, до того момента, пока ответ Вам не принес пользу. Таким образом, если Вам понравился самоответ пользователя и Вы видите пользу от такого вопроса/ответа стоит сказать спасибо(галка вверх).

Comment: Минус за дубликат - с чего бы это? о_О

Comment: @Alex, не-не-не! Чем больше минимально отличных формулировок одного и того же вопроса, тем выше вероятность того, что на к-л вопрос можно найти ответ спрашивая по разному!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, уже подумали над этим) Конечно же Вы с Qwertiy правы)

Comment: @avp а в чем Вы видите банальность? в очевидном ответе?)

Comment: Специальный [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34905/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-----) для обсуждения всего, не относящегося к вопросу и ответу. =)

Comment: @Alex, конечно.

Comment: @avp ну так другой ответ здесь и не дашь) но, каким бы очевидным не был ответ на вопрос, он должен быть, чтобы общество могло проголосовать и далее придерживаться какого-либо курса по +/- за самоответы. Здесь все-таки более менее командная игра) Если у Вас иное мнение, опубликуйте Ваше мнение по поводу вопроса, этим Вы принесете пользу обществу.

Comment: @Alex, вот мне кажется, что толку будет больше, если в основном руководствоваться собственным чувством здравого смысла, а не соотношением голосов в каких-то обсуждениях на Мете.

Comment: @avp и да и нет. пример - споры по поводу приветствий, просьб и т.п.  не все новые пользователи понимают о чем so, что и как можно спрашивать, а что нельзя. И подобные вопросы/ответы на мете, на наш взгляд, в большей степени как раз таки для них, а не для пользователей имеющих хорошую репутацию и понимающих для чего существует se.

Comment: @Alex, Вы серьезно считаете, что люди для которых Вы это тут пишете читают Мету? И почему Вы решили что какая-то часть пользователей имеет право диктовать остальным о чем можно спрашивать, а о чем нет? А вот приветствия и просьбы -- на суть не влияют, можно вымарывать (только в свежих, иначе вся старая мутота вылазит наверх).

Comment: @avp читают или нет - это роли не играет, важно понимать, что вас никто не заставляет следовать тем курсом, что и остальные, но основным правилам следовать все же стоит. Обсуждение есть выражение мыслей в отношении какого-либо вопроса и это не обязательный постулат, т.е., например, возникнет когда-либо у кого-нибудь такой же вопрос, можно сослать его на данную страницу, но при этом пользователь может не согласиться с высказываниями и сделать так как он считает правильным.

Comment: Ух ты, как ответ почистился :)

Comment: @Qwertiy убрали лишнюю информацию)

Answer (score 4):

Дополнительно поощрять не надо.

Привлекать внимание уместно.

Comment: Не надо поощрять экспертов, новичков или тех и других?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, никого специально поощрять не надо. Вряд ли автор самоответа должен как-то отличаться от остальных ответивших, что  тут, что в других вопросах (понятно, что галку он себе поставить не может).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет, ибо с большой вероятностью начнётся такое поведение, когда человек создал вопрос и тут же написал для него ответ.

Со стороны это выглядит как "накрутка" рейтинга в обход основного способа: задай вопрос и жди ответа, попутно продолжая поиски решения самому.

И в таком случае желание плюсануть пропадает. Ну а если же видно, что прошло некоторое время после создания вопроса, то автор и так получит свою награду в виде заплюсованного вопроса и ответа.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы совсем не поняли вопрос.

Comment: "Автор — эксперт в некоторой теме. Он формулирует некоторую популярную, важную и/или интересную ему проблему и описывает её решение в качестве ответа." — про такие ситуации и писал. На ruSO не редкость такое поведение, когда "эксперт" спросил и через 30 секунд тут же ответил. Как это воспринимается описал в своём ответе.

Comment: ок, понял. У меня есть десяток таких ответов. Считаете, я их ради накрутки писал?

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет, ибо не знаю мотивов, речь про восприятие такого поведения. Может быть цель сохранить знания, в виде вопроса-ответов, а может быть ещё с какой-то целью. Одно могу утверждать наверняка: когда появляется такой вопрос, к решению над которым сразу же приступают несколько человек, и потом выясняется — когда планируешь добавить решение, обновляя страницу — что ответ уже дали, причём очень качественный (на который нужно потратить не 5 и даже не 20 минут), сразу после самого вопроса, то это, мягко говоря, огорчает отвечающих.