# Как мне поделиться с сообществом рабочим кодом?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, самоответы

Я задаю очень много, иногда тупых, вопросов на StackOverflow на русском.
Есть вопросы с ответами и без. На некоторые вопросы я сам нахожу ответ после того как уже опубликовал вопрос. И на данный момент у меня образовалась ситуация, когда у меня нету ни вопроса, ни ответа, а я просто гуглил, пробовал, и в итоге у меня получился рабочий метод, который мне очень помог.

Я уже много читал здесь вопросов про самоответы, но так и не понял пока что как опубликовать код, который у меня получился. Может есть где-то какая-то специальная страничка, где нету вопросов, а есть только рабочий код, который публикуют участники?
Этот код возможно тестируется и может пропустится или нет для публикации на этой страничке. Либо у меня есть второй вариант - опубликовать вопрос, а потом сразу закинуть ответ. Я видел много комментариев, где участники жалуются на маленькое количество реально нормальных вопросов, и вот у меня сейчас есть вроде рабочий код (просто кроме меня его никто не тестировал).

Дорогие участники и пользователи сообщества, как вы мне посоветуете поступить в данной ситуации? Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/605310/178988

Comment: та вроде устраивает, просто я спрашивал как мне делится своими наработками в пределах данного ресурса

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы уже озвучили правильный вариант: [вопрос-самоответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2393/213987). У меня например таких полно. Я правда не код нахожу - а ответ на en so, поэтому у меня чаще посты-переводы. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/859592/213987).

Понимаете, просто опубликовать рабочий код мало - нужно показать, что за проблему этот код решает, в какой задаче понадобился. Поэтому нужно описать в вопросе эту проблему/задачу - и в ответе уже приводить код, возможно с пояснениями словами.

Просто код можно закинуть на ресурсы типа github или различные fiddle-сайты. Но там по сравнению со stackoverflow нет возможности пояснить код словами или обсудить с участниками. А я бывало публиковал код самоответом, чтобы посмотреть, какие замечания выскажут или укажут, что есть и более эффективные варианты задачи.

Comment: спасибо большое, вы очень хорошо все объяснили)

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, что вы не совсем корректны в своём вопросе здесь. Я имею ввиду вашу формулировку.

> И на данный момент у меня образовалась ситуация, когда у меня нету ни вопроса, ни ответа, а я просто гуглил, пробовал, и в итоге у меня получился рабочий метод, который мне очень помог.

Любой рабочий код решает какие-то конкретные задачи (иначе нет смысла его публиковать), а значит из него нетрудно выделить сам вопрос. Для того, чтобы что-то публиковать здесь, вы в любом случае должны будете добавить какие-то пояснения к вашему коду, а также внятно сформулировать запрос к сообществу.

---

Вообще из данного вопроса непонятно, требуется ли желание просто поделиться кодом или нужна по нему обратная связь. Рассмотрим оба случая.

### Случай, когда нужна обратная связь. Вы полагаете, что данный код есть куда улучшать, но вы не знаете как именно.

Если вам нужна обратная связь по поводу вашего кода, то вам следует описать контекст в котором данный код применяется и какого рода обратную связь вы хотите (надёжность кода, производительность кода, потенциальные баги, уязвимости и т.д.) и затем привести фрагмент кода, который решает какую-то задачу или подзадачу. На данные вопросы следует навешивать метку [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0).

Также крайне рекомендую, ваш вопрос, связанный с инспекцией кода, перести и дополнительно задать [на специализированном англоязычном сайте, посвящённому инспекции кода](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) и добавить на него ссылку в русскоязычном вопросе. Таким образом вы получите больше обратной связи и объедините усилия двух сообществ.

### Случай, когда обратная связь допустима, но сильной потребности в ней нет.

Вы верно предположили вариант самоответа, здесь он подходит. Но здесь, разумеется, придётся тщательно подойти к формулированию вопроса. Крайне важно, чтобы сам вопрос не выглядет притянутым за уши к вашему ответу — иначе сам вопрос выглядит как самопиар своего кода. На качественно сформулированный и актуальный для широких масс вопрос придёт много людей из поисковиков и оценит ваш ответ.

Настоятельно рекомендую посмотреть, не был ли задан подобный вопрос — возможно, под ваше решение уже есть популярный вопрос и вам нет смысла создавать дубликат.

И также здесь будет полезно поискать подобный вопрос на enSO или самому его создать там и добавить ваш ответ. А после этого воспользоваться [механизмом ассоциаций](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/220571).

Comment: вот я создал такой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879444/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-android, мне будет интересно услышать ваше мнение по поводу его формулировки.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Не увидел явных минусов в вопросе, мне он кажется полезным (менять язык в мобильных приложениях без перезапуска очень даже полезно, простите за тавтологию). К сожаленью, не спец по андроиду, чтобы дать более глубокую обратную связь.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, для меня любое мнение очень полезно)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Да, типичный вопрос-самоответ. Не разбираясь глубоко в андроидах вижу по косвенным признакам весьма полезный и содержательный ответ. Если у вас есть ещё подобные вопросы-самоответы - пишите изредка когда будет время - так понемногу накопится много полезной информации: полезно иногда проговаривать вслух свои мысли, чтобы лучше усвоилось.